# installing cx-oracle and dev-tools on centos

Tags: python, django, pip, centos, cx-oracle

We have a `(python2.7/django-1.10)` project working on Ubuntu 14.04. Since the end of 14.04 is near, we are migrating to CentOS(7) for a particular reason.

The error I am getting is below when I run `pip install -r requirements.txt`

```
Installing collected packages: cx-Oracle, Django, python-openid, requests, oauthlib, requests-oauthlib, django-allauth, django-angular, sqlparse, django-debug-toolbar, django-debug-toolbar-request-history, django-debug-toolbar-template-profiler, django-debug-toolbar-template-timings, djangorestframework, execnet, greenlet, gevent, gunicorn, meld3, pyasn1, pyOpenSSL, ndg-httpsclient, ntlm-auth, pytz, xmltodict, requests-ntlm, pywinrm, sh, supervisor
  Running setup.py install for cx-Oracle ... error
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-JZMDHk/cx-Oracle/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-stOsUC/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_ext
    building 'cx_Oracle' extension
    creating build
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7-11g
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -I/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/rdbms/demo -I/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/rdbms/public -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c cx_Oracle.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7-11g/cx_Oracle.o -DBUILD_VERSION=5.2.1
    unable to execute gcc: No such file or directory
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-JZMDHk/cx-Oracle/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-stOsUC/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-JZMDHk/cx-Oracle/
```

Then after some fiddling, I tried installing `gcc` with following command.

```
yum install gcc
```

and the output is

```
Failed to set locale, defaulting to C
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
github_git-lfs/x86_64/signature                                                              |  833 B  00:00:00     
github_git-lfs/x86_64/signature                                                              | 1.0 kB  00:00:00 !!! 
github_git-lfs-source/signature                                                              |  833 B  00:00:00     
github_git-lfs-source/signature                                                              | 1.0 kB  00:00:00 !!! 
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
...
...
...
...
Error: Package: glibc-devel-2.17-196.el7_4.2.x86_64 (ultra-centos-7.4-updates)
           Requires: glibc = 2.17-196.el7_4.2
           Installed: glibc-2.17-222.el7.x86_64 (installed)
               glibc = 2.17-222.el7
           Available: glibc-2.17-196.el7.x86_64 (ultra-centos-7.4-base)
               glibc = 2.17-196.el7
           Available: glibc-2.17-196.el7_4.2.x86_64 (ultra-centos-7.4-updates)
               glibc = 2.17-196.el7_4.2
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

So the basically problem is that I want `dev-tools` installed to build and install `cx-Oracle` but somehow I am not able to install it.

Is there anything special need to be done on CentOS.

```
yum list glibc*
Failed to set locale, defaulting to C
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Installed Packages
glibc.x86_64                                    2.17-222.el7                                installed               
glibc-common.x86_64                             2.17-222.el7                                installed               
Available Packages
glibc-devel.x86_64                              2.17-196.el7_4.2                            ultra-centos-7.4-updates
glibc-headers.x86_64                            2.17-196.el7_4.2                            ultra-centos-7.4-updates
glibc-static.x86_64                             2.17-196.el7_4.2                            ultra-centos-7.4-updates
glibc-utils.x86_64                              2.17-196.el7_4.2                            ultra-centos-7.4-updates
```

**yum repolist**

```
Failed to set locale, defaulting to C
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
repo id                                 repo name                                                             status
!github_git-lfs/x86_64                  github_git-lfs                                                          46
!github_git-lfs-source                  github_git-lfs-source                                                    0
nginx/x86_64                            nginx repo                                                             513
packages-microsoft-com-prod             packages-microsoft-com-prod                                            297
ultra-centos-7.4-base                   UltraServe CentOS-7.4 - Base                                          7407
ultra-centos-7.4-extras                 UltraServe CentOS-7.4 - Extras                                         401
ultra-centos-7.4-updates                UltraServe CentOS-7.4 - Updates                                       1836
ultra-centos-7.x-newrelic-monitoring    UltraServe CentOS-7.x - New Relic Infrastructure Monitoring Agent        1
ultra-centos-7.x-ultrarepo              UltraServe CentOS-7.x - UltraServe Repo Packages                        32
repolist: 10533
```

Comment: Can you include the output of `yum list glibc*`?

Comment: ok, something's wrong with your repos.....what about `yum repolist` output?

Comment: @Deeh, I thought so, Updated.

Comment: @Deeh any suggestions?

Comment: Basically, your system tries to install `glibc-devel-2.17-196` which requires `glibc-2.17-196`.  But you already have the latest `glibc-2.17-222`. I'm not very familiar with Ultra repos, from a quick search, it looks like it's a AWS box.

Comment: yeah, you are right, it is AWS community box

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191105/discussion-between-deeh-and-kishor-pawar).